# Shell script > Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, bash, shell

I am trying to convert this Shell script into a Ruby script.
I allready have the Rubular Regex done but i dont know how to imply the reg ex into a ruby script.

Shell Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="./NA_Hosts.txt"
            if [ ! -e  $file ];then
                            sed -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A /,/g' \
                            -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A /,/g' \
                            -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A /,/g' \
                            -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A /,/g' \
                            -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A    /,/g' \
                            -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A  /,/g' \
                            -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A /,/g' \
                            -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A   /,/g' /tmp/testing/dig_whole_ipss.txt > ./NA_Hosts.txt
                echo ${txtgrn}Script executed successfully.${txtrst}
                cat ./NA_Hosts.txt >> ./NA_Temp.txt
                            exit
                        else
                read -r -p "${txtred}ATTENTION!${txtrst} Generating this file will replace the old one. Do you wish to continue? [y/N] " response
                if [[ $response =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]];then
                    sed -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A /,/g' \
                                -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A /,/g' \
                                -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A /,/g' \
                                -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A /,/g' \
                                -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A    /,/g' \
                                -e 's/*.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A  /,/g' \
                                -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A /,/g' \
                                -e 's/.ipss.test.net. 60 IN A   /,/g' /tmp/testing/dig_whole_ipss.txt > ./NA_Hosts.txt
                    changecount=`cat NA_Temp.txt NA_Hosts.txt | sort | uniq -u | wc -l`
                                echo "There have been made ${txtred}$changecount${txtrst} total changes."
                                echo ${txtgrn}NA-Hosts file has been successfully updated! ${txtrst}
                    cat NA_Hosts.txt|grep ""s-vd"" >> dslamlist.txt
                    cat NA_Hosts.txt|grep ""s-vh"" >> dslamlist.txt
                    cat ./NA_Hosts.txt > ./NA_Temp.txt
                    if [[ "$changecount">"$sendmailtreshold" ]];then
                        mail -s "Notification: NA-Host File updated!" John.test@test.com<<-MYTEXT
                        Node DB | NA-Host File
                        The NA-Host File has been successfully updated.
                        There has been made $changecount changes.
                        You're receiving this notification because you are a on the list of receivers.
                        *** This is an automatically generated email, please do not reply ***
                        MYTEXT
                    fi
                else
                                echo ${txtred}Script aborted.${txtrst}
                            exit
                    fi
```

The shell script works fine.

Rubular REG EX:

```
(ipc-\D{3,4}\d{3}-s-v.-\d{2})\.ipss.test.net\.\s+\d+\s+IN\s+A\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)
```

The Goal of the ruby script should be to get this format:

```
ipc-zuc650-s-vd-04.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A 10.150.90.110
```

Into this:

```
ipc-zuc650-s-vd-04,10.150.90.110
```

Comment: I read the title as *Shell script is superior to Ruby*, which is a debatable point ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you're looking to do:

```
regex = /(ipc-\D{3,4}\d{3}-s-v.-\d{2})\.ipss.test.net\.\s+\d+\s+IN\s+A\s+(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/
string = "ipc-zuc650-s-vd-04.ipss.test.net. 3600 IN A 10.150.90.110"
string.scan(regex).map{ |host,ip| "#{host},#{ip}" }
```

which results in an array as follows: `["ipc-zuc650-s-vd-04,10.150.90.110"]`

Documentation for String#scan can be found at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-scan